# Set URL for blueprint views individually

Tags: flask

In Flask, I can change the prefix of a blueprint, but is there a way to change the URl of an individual view?

For example, say I have the blueprint `fish`. It has a bunch of views, like `fish.view`, `fish.edit`, `fish.index`, and `fish.search`. The default prefix of the blueprint is `/fishes/`, so the views end up at as `/fishes/<id>/`, `/fishes/<id>/edit`, `/fishes/`, and `/fishes/search`.

How do I change the URL of `fishes.search` to just `/search` instead of `/fishes/search`, without changing the URLs of the other views?

I know I could do this:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search(**kwargs):
    return fish_views.search(**kwargs)
```

However, if I did that, then `url_for('fish.search')` would still return `/fishes/search`. I want `url_for` to return the preferred URL.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from . import fish_views
    app.register_blueprint(fish_views.blueprint)
    app.change_view_url_somehow('fish.search', '/search')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without monkey patching Flask's `route` decorator or leveraging `add_url_for` manually, the easiest way is to attach `/search` only to the main app specifying the endpoint that the fish blueprint would ultimately resolve to by default:

```
@app.route('/search', endpoint='fish.search')
def search(**kwargs):
    pass
```